# How to combine several variables inline in Svelte

Tags: sveltekit

I define a path like `{base}/{$page.params.id}/share` in SvelteKit. I'm struggling to set the is-active class when the actual URL is equal.

```
<li class:is-active={$page.url.pathname === ?????}>
  <a href="{base}/{$page.params.id}/share">Share</a>
</li>
```

Getting the url works (`$page.url.pathname`), but how do I compare it with the combined string `{base}/{$page.params.id}/share`.

I'm not able to put this in the compare section (tried several things like brackets, curly brackets around it without result).

I used another approach to make the path name, however I have the same issue when I want to combine the variables (path and subpath) inline.

```
$: path = base+"/"+data.session.id;
```

```
<li class:is-active={$page.url.pathname === (path+"/"+share) }>
  <a href="{path}/share">Share</a>
</li>
```

This `(path+"/"+share)` doesn't work either.

Probably I miss something basic, but I can't figure it out in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I deal with an issue like this, I try to figure out if the statement is actually working. An easy way to test this is by assigning a variable to the result of the comparison operation, logging it, then passing it into your markup.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```html
<script>
    // snip
    
    // bind "is_eq" to the boolean result. updates when any of the values change.
    $: is_eq = $page.url.pathname === `${base}/${data.session.id}/share`
    
    // log "is_eq" if it changes
    $: console.log(is_eq)

    // snip
</script>

<!-- snip -->

    <li class:is-active={is_eq}>
      <a href="{path}/share">Share</a>
    </li>

<!-- snip -->
```

If you see `true` in your console, then something is up with your class. If you don't see `true`, then it's a sign that there's something wrong with your `$page.url.pathname` or combined string, which can then be looked into further using the same strategy. :)

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I helped me to debug the comparison. Based on your answer I could figure out how to deal with it inline (template literal usage).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out based on the answer of @kalkonline.

```
$: path = base+"/"+data.session.id;
```

```
<li class:is-active={$page.url.pathname === path}>
  <a href="{path}">Settings</a>
</li>
<li class:is-active={$page.url.pathname === (`${path}/share`) }>
  <a href="{path}/share">Share</a>
</li>
<li class:is-active={$page.url.pathname === (`${path}/show`) }>
  <a href="{path}/show">Show</a>
</li>
```

Still, I'm curious why sometimes have the put a $ symbol in front of the {} (like in the comparison with `${path}`) and not when I use it in href, like `{path}`.

Comment: The `${path}` syntax is part of JS, it's called a template literal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
The `{ ... }` syntax is how you insert JS statements into Svelte.